# Why does this QWidget eventFilter not prevent the other widget from processing?

Tags: qt

`MyWidget` is a subclass of `QDialog` and holds a `QTextEdit * m_view` member.

I want to capture right-clicks on the `QTextEdit` and show a different menu from the standard one.

At the moment, the menu which `MyWidget::context_menu` creates is shown, and then afterwards the standard `QTextEdit` context menu is also shown.

```
MyWidget :: MyWidget ()
{
    // ...
    m_view -> installEventFilter (this);
}

bool
MyWidget :: eventFilter (QObject * obj, QEvent * e)
{
    if (m_view == obj && QEvent :: MouseButtonPress == e -> type ())
    {
        auto me = dynamic_cast <QMouseEvent *> (e);

        if (Qt :: RightButton == me -> button ())
        {
            context_menu (m_view -> mapToGlobal (me -> pos ()));

            e -> accept ();

            return true;
        }
        else
            return QDialog :: eventFilter (obj, e);
    }
    else
        return QDialog :: eventFilter (obj, e);
}
```

Even more curiously -- if I left-click or right-click outside my custom menu to lose its focus then the standard context menu does *not* appear -- it only appears if I choose one of my menu items!

The `eventFilter` both returns true and calls `e->accept()`, so why does the standard menu also appear?

If there's another Right Way To Do It, that's fine, but please also explain why the event is handled by both widgets.

(Incidentally I'd also like to know why both `return true` and `QEvent::accept()` are in the design -- it seems redundant but Qt is quite intelligently designed, so what's the reason?)

Comment: What about `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` event? It might be that the `QTextEdit` context menu shown on that event and not on mouse press.

Comment: If I capture MouseButtonRelease instead then my menu doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Do you know why? Does the native context menu shown if you handle mouse release event?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to show a custom context menu is to set the [`context menu policy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) to [`Qt::CustomContextMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum).
Then use the [`QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint & pos)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal to show your own menu.

```
m_view->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(m_view, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(showContextMenu(QPoint)));
```

By the way, the reason for your event filter not working, is that you're checking the wrong object. I'm not sure which object is responsible for triggering the `QEvent::ContextMenu` event during the `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` event. But even if you got it to work by filtering out the mouse button release event, it would be wrong. This is not the only case when the context menu would be shown. There is also a menu button on most keyboards that will trigger the context menu. But if you want to filter the context menu out, you should check that the event is `QEvent::ContextMenu` and that the object is `m_view->viewport()` and not the `m_view` itself:

```
  if(e->type() == QEvent::ContextMenu && obj == m_view->viewport())
```